# Cómo poner si EditText vacío me salga un error?

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo una aplicación muy sencilla donde estoy poniendo 3 `editText`, con números enteros positivos, y hago un cálculo. Si relleno esos 3 `editText` y pincho en "calcular" va todo perfecto, pero si dejo 1 , 2 o los 3 vacío me salta error y mi aplicación deja de funcionar.

¿Cómo hago para que al dejarlo vacío lo interprete como un "0"? He probado ya muchísimas cosas y nada... siempre me sale error y se me sale de la aplicación... mi código es este:

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_espaciales);

        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.suma1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.suma2);
        et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.suma3);
        Button sumarsumar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sumarsumar);
        elresultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);
      //  textMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);

        //textMessage.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
        if (et1.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            et1.setError("This field can not be blank");

        if (et2.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            et2.setError("This field can not be blank");

        if (et3.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            et3.setError("This field can not be blank");
            //c=0;
        sumarsumar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


        double a = Double.valueOf(et1.getText().toString()); // Le saco valor entero y lo pongo en a
        double b = Double.valueOf(et2.getText().toString()); // Le saco valor entero y lo pongo en b
        double c = Double.valueOf(et3.getText().toString());


        double notafinal = a*0.35 + b*0.45+c*0.2; // RESULTADO FINAL
```

Como podéis observar he puesto `if(et1.getText().toString()..... )` para que el usuario vea en cada `edtiText` un `Warning` como que deben completarlo, si no, les saldría error, pero eso es como medida desesperada, eso yo no lo quiero, quiero que puedan dejarlo vacío

---

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text=" 2º" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=" 1º" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="    PRÁCTICAS" />

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/suma2"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/suma3"
    android:layout_width="169dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/suma1"
    android:layout_width="166dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sumarsumar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/suma3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultado"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/suma1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sumarsumar"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Usa la función `isEmpty()` que te devuelve si el valor del `EditText` es vacío :

```
 if(!numpad.getText().toString().isEmpty()){ 

       //Devuelve alguna cadena de texto

 }else{

       //Devuelve vacío

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Si únicamente deseas validar si existe o no contenido puede ser de varias formas, por ejemplo:

Para validar si no contiene ningún carácter:

```
if(editText.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
    //EditText Vacio!
```

Para validar si contiene algún carácter:

```
if(editText.getText().toString().length() > 0 )
    //EditText contiene algún caracter!
```

Esta sería una versión que elimina los espacios en blanco usando el método [`trim()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim()) :

```
if(et1.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
   //EditText Vacio!
```

Pero creo que **la mejor opción para validar si esta vació o no el contenido del [`EditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) sería mediante el método [isEmpty()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())** :

```
if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
   //EditText contiene algún caracter!
```

Answer (score 0):

La comprobación de si los EditText son vacíos lo estas haciendo en la declaración con lo cual al principio estará siempre vacío, debes controlar los EditText en el momento en el que el usuario pulsa el botón:

```
sumarsumar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

   double a = 0;
   //Comprobamos que no estén vacios
   if (et1.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
       a = Double.valueOf(et1.getText().toString()); 
   } else {
      //¿Quieres hacer algo si el usuario no ha añadido nada?
   }

   ...
```

De esta manera si el usuario no escribe nada en el EditText por defecto tendrá el valor 0.

---

Veo que estabas haciendo la comparación con:
`if (et1.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))`

Estas usando equalsIgnoreCase, ese método sirve para comparar dos cadenas de texto omitiendo que sean mayúsculas o minúsculas, por ejemplo:

`if("texto".equalsIgnoreCase("TEXTO"))`
Daría como resultado TRUE

`if("texto".equals("TEXTO"))`
Daría como resultado FALSE

Comment: al final ya lo he logrado, muchisimas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Muy fácil, espero que me entiendas.

He hecho aplicaciones parecidas y lo que siempre hago es cuando hago `Touch` en el botón me haga el proceso de transformación.

Primero declaras 3 auxiliares que transformen todo lo que escribas a una cadena.

```
Override
public void onClick(View view) {

String auxi=et1.getText().toString();
String auxi2=et2.getText().toString();
String auxi3=et3.getText().toString();

}
```

Después agregas una condición que si uno de los 3 `EditText` el valor que toma es 0.

```
Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    String auxi=et1.getText().toString();
    String auxi2=et2.getText().toString();
    String auxi3=et3.getText().toString();

    if(auxi.matches("") //Solo es una acción así que no es necesario las llaves
         double a = 0;  //Si no hay nada le agregamos 0
    else
         double a = Integer.parseInt(auxi1); //De lo contrario lo transformamos.

    //lo mismo con los otros 2.
    if(auxi2.matches("")
         double b= 0; 
    else
         double b = Integer.parseInt(auxi2);


    if(auxi3.matches("")
         double c= 0; 
    else
         double c = Integer.parseInt(auxi3);  

    //Por ultimo la operación. 
    double notafinal = a*0.35 + b*0.45+c*0.2; // RESULTADO FINAL
    ....   
}
```

Ya desde ahí lo terminas el algoritmo, el mio no es el mejor del mundo pero ya para mas "EditText" uso otros algoritmos para mejorar el rendimiento.

Answer (score 0):

yo hice esto para que no se iniciara la siguiente actividad hasta que se llenaran los campos

```
Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btncalcumod40);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){

                //hasta aqui funciona paraaaaaaaaa

                if (etañosmod40.getText().toString().isEmpty()==true) {
                    etañosmod40.setError("campo obligatorio");
                }
                if (etsemreco.getText().toString().isEmpty() == true) {
                    etsemreco.setError("campo obligatorio");
                }


                if (etañosmod40.getText().toString().isEmpty()==false) {
                    if (etsemreco.getText().toString().isEmpty() == false) {


                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), resulmod40.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                        EnviarDatos();
                    }
```

Comment: No es necesario comparar " == true" y para comparar si es "== false" con castearlo con el caracter "!" seria suficiente Ej:
if (!etañosmod40.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
// Esto seria como ==false
}

if (etañosmod40.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
// Esto seria como ==true
}

Answer (score -1):

Pues únicamente tienes que validar que el txt este vacío, y si es así pues que lo llene con un string "0"

```
Double _default = "0.0";

if(et1.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

et1.setText(Double.Parse(_default)); 
}
```

Con esto estás llenando el et1 con 0.0 en caso de que esté vacío.

Answer (score -1):

Una forma fácil de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
String precio= this.precio.getText().toString();


if (precio.equals("")) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Ha dejado campos vacios", 
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Para comparar si un String es vacío existe el método .isEmpty().

Answer (score -1):

Sumar números aún cuando una casilla esté vacía

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText et1,et2,et3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
        et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
    }

    public void sumar(View view) {
        String a=et1.getText().toString();
        String b=et2.getText().toString();
        String c=et3.getText().toString();

        String aux1 = "0";
        String aux2 = "0";
        String aux3 = "0";
        if(a.isEmpty()){

            a=aux1;
        }
        if(b.isEmpty()){

            b=aux2;
        }
        if(c.isEmpty()){

            c=aux3;
        }

        int num1=Integer.parseInt(a);
        int num2=Integer.parseInt(b);
        int num3=Integer.parseInt(c);

        int sumar=num1+num2+num3;
        String resultado=String.valueOf(sumar);

        tv1.setText(resultado);

    }
```

Comment: Para que tu respuesta sea útil, deberías explicar cual fue el error del OP y cómo funciona tu solución. Así el resto aprenderemos algo.